# In CSMA/CD what does Carrier Sensing stands for? What does it mean?

Tags: switch, ethernet, network

For someone who does not speak English as a native language some acronyms can be really confusing and I would like to make sure that I understand how were this acronyms formed and what was the initial thinking behind them.

I am not exactly sure what the term Carrier refers to in terms of computer networking. Is the copper considered carrier?

What does sensing the carrier mean?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Carrier refers to an electrical signal that is modulated, in the same way as radio transmissions.

Sensing refers to detecting the presence of the carrier signal.